# service for mongodb 3.4 server on SLES 12 SP2 Doesn't start(Raspberry Pi 3)

Tags: linux, mongodb

The link below was the source:
https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=server:database&package=mongodb

It was the only mongodb 3.4 which could be installed correctly but unfortunately it's service does not start with error saying "Cannot start server. The default storage engine 'wiredTiger' is not available with this build of mongod. Please specify a different storage engine explicitly, e.g. --storageEngine=mmapv1., terminating".

Any suggestions to fix the problem?